# If first forall records exception occur, the second forall is not execute what to do?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    ERROR_COUNT NUMBER;
    errno number;
    e_msg varchar2(50);
    e_idx varchar2(20);

    TYPE emp_type IS TABLE OF emp_source%ROWTYPE;
    EMP_VAR emp_type;

    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM emp_source;

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;

    loop
        FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO EMP_VAR;

        BEGIN
            FORALL i in 1 .. EMP_VAR.COUNT save exceptions       
            insert INTO emp_target (e_id,e_name,sal) values (EMP_VAR(i).E_ID,EMP_VAR(i).E_NAME,EMP_VAR(i).SAL);

            FORALL i in 1 .. EMP_VAR.COUNT save exceptions       
            insert INTO department_target (dep_name) values (EMP_VAR(i).dep_name);

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN others THEN
                ERROR_COUNT := sql%bulk_exceptions.count;

                for i in 1 .. ERROR_COUNT
                loop
                    errno := sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code;
                    e_msg   := sqlerrm(-errno);
                    e_idx   := sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index;

                    insert into emp_save_exc values(errno,e_msg,e_idx);
                end loop;
        END;
        exit when c1%notfound;
    end loop;

    close c1;
    commit;
END;
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  I try to imagine what I would do if a colleague came to my desk with the print out above and said the words in the title. My response would probably be short and a little sharp.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a BEGIN/END block around the first FORALL and handle the exception like this:

```
BEGIN
    FORALL i in 1 .. EMP_VAR.COUNT save exceptions       
    insert INTO emp_target (e_id,e_name,sal) values (EMP_VAR(i).E_ID,EMP_VAR(i).E_NAME,EMP_VAR(i).SAL);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN ...
END;
```

You can also turn each block into a procedure to make your code more structured:

```
DECLARE
    ...
    PROCEDURE insert_emp_target (p_emp_var emp_type) IS
    BEGIN
        FORALL i in 1 .. EMP_VAR.COUNT save exceptions       
            insert INTO emp_target (e_id,e_name,sal) 
                values (EMP_VAR(i).E_ID,EMP_VAR(i).E_NAME,EMP_VAR(i).SAL);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN ...
    END;

    PROCEDURE insert_dept_target (p_emp_var emp_type) IS
    ...
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    loop
        FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO EMP_VAR;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        insert_emp_target (emp_var);
        insert_dept_target (emp_var);
        ...
    end loop;
    close c1;
    commit;    
END;
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, but i know about this scenario, this is simple procedure suppose i have use 10-insert within forall, in this situation each FORALL wise use BEGIN / END is not good idea..

Comment: Suppose 10-times or more then use BEGIN / END,  the  particular procedure is very complex.

Comment: So why does have ten BEGIN/END blocks with separate exception handlers increase the complexity? The complexity comes from the starting design, the decision to have to ten FORALL statements in one procedure. Everything else flows form there.

Comment: @sygops - the procedure doesn't become more complex it simply has more lines of code. If each operation in each FORALL can be completed independent of the others then this is what you need. That seems to be how your transaction needs to be.